# Inline Entity Form - How to change label for the EDIT button and REMOVE button

Tags: entities

I try to modify the 'Edit' and 'Remove' label on the buttons displayed in the IEF table.
I can modify the 'Add new node' buttons with the code bellow

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'CONTENTTYPE_node_form') {
    /*
    * Modify the Add node button when it's the first one
    */
    $form['MY_FIELD']['und']['form']['actions']['ief_add_save']['#value'] = t('CUSTOM TEXT');
    /*
    * Modify the Add node button when there is at least one node
    */
    $form['MY_FIELD']['und']['actions']['ief_add']['#value'] = t('CUSTOM TEXT');
  }
}
```

But I can't make it work for the Edit or Remove buttons

For the Edit button, I tried to add in this function:

```
$form['MY_FIELD']['und']['form']['actions']['ief_entity_edit']['#value'] = t('CUSTOM TEXT');
```

Doesn't work

```
$form['MY_FIELD']['und']['actions']['ief_entity_edit']['#value'] = t('CUSTOM TEXT');
```

Doesn't work either

Any idea ?

Comment: How did you edit the 'Add new button'

Comment: I created a custom module and use the hook_form_alter() function. (updated in the question)

Answer (score 1):

Try [form after build](https://www.appnovation.com/blog/drupal-tip-using-formafter-build). it may give you solution.

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'CONTENTTYPE_node_form') {
    /*
    * Modify the Add node button when it's the first one
    */
    $form['MY_FIELD']['und']['form']['actions']['ief_add_save']['#value'] = t('CUSTOM TEXT');
    /*
    * Modify the Add node button when there is at least one node
    */
    $form['MY_FIELD']['und']['actions']['ief_add']['#value'] = t('CUSTOM TEXT');
    $form['#after_build'][] = 'yourmodulename_after_build'; //Calls function 
  }
}
```

Use dpm($form) or print_r($form) to find the edit button id